# Выход за пределы массива C++

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, адрес

При выходе за пределы динамического массива программа впервые вместо вылета с ошибкой 0xC0000005 выводит "once (адрес) is (значение)". Из-за чего это возникает и как фиксить?

P.S. Code::Blocks 17.12 C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int *arr = 0;
    arr = new int [3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) std::cout << arr + i << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) arr[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]

Comment: Вы точно именно этот код компилируете? Хоть это и неопределенное поведение, но не может он такого печатать...

Answer (score 6):

Выход за пределы массива (а тут еще и обращение к неинициализированному объекту) является *неопределенным поведением*. Неопределенное поведение означает, что [результат компиляции и исполнения программы непредсказуем](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/). Ожидание конкретного результата, в том числе аварийного завершения программы, при наличии в ней неопределенного поведения является неправильным.

Для исправления есть только один вариант - устранение неопределенного поведения в программе.